# Solr search numbers in word form

Tags: ruby, search, solr

I am indexing couple of documents that contain numericals with text, which are getting indexed as expected. Ex: "6 flags is a popular amusement park", now when I search for "6 flags", I am able to retrieve document without issues, however when I search for "Six flags" , solr doesn't return any document, I have defined a custom type called "text_field" , and it's definition is as follows:

```html
<fieldType name="text_field" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory" rulefiles="Latn:Latin-whitespace.rbbi"/>
     
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="false" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" 
                catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <!-- Remove external punctuation; spell text does exact match -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^\p{Punct}*(.*?)\p{Punct}*$" 
          replacement="$1"/>
        <!-- acronyms should be case-sensitive at index time, otherwise common words get expanded (like 'it') -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="acronym_synonyms_inline.txt" ignoreCase="false" />
        <!-- DIRE: be aggressive about folding diacritics; also normalizes -->
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="new_name_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
        <!-- DIRE: Only do more aggressive synonyms at index time. -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="text_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <!-- DIRE: Multi-term synonyms break highlighting when searching on
             words after the first.  Here we treat each member term as a
             synonym in order to get proper highlighting. Then we boost via a
             hidden field to get the phrase matching -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="expand_synonyms_inline.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StemmerOverrideFilterFactory" dictionary="stemdict.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>  
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory" rulefiles="Latn:Latin-whitespace.rbbi"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="false" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^\p{Punct}*(.*?)\p{Punct}*$" 
          replacement="$1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" 
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" 
                catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- DIRE: always do compound splitting on queries; we currently can't
             do multiword synonyms at index time unless we protect the terms from tokenization. -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="expand_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <!-- acronyms should be case-insensitive at query time, since users often don't bother -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="acronym_synonyms_query.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StemmerOverrideFilterFactory" dictionary="stemdict.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>  
    </fieldType>
```

which filter or tokenizer I should add while Indexing so that I can query numbers in their word form in solr, I am using solr 6.5

Comment: Depends on how far you want to go; in general, a synonym filter with `1, one`, `2, two` etc. should be good enough.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks, Do you suggest to add word form of numbers in a textfile and provide it to synonymFilterFactory ?

Comment: @MatsLindh, adding synonyms list in a file works,  how about creating a custom filter factory that generates this synonyms , will that work ?

Comment: Sure, if you want to do that, go ahead. But it might be easier to just write a snippet that generates the synonym file instead, that way you won't have to maintain a custom filter and distribute it across nodes. Depends on how many terms you want to expand, though (if you want to support "one thousand three hundred and forty five" as well)